# How to solve "Unknown provider" issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

When I use ui-router with a resolve it gives a "Unknown provider" error. Below I mentioned the error, that printed on the browser console.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appFacilityListProvider <- appFacilityList <- facilityController 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=appFacilityListProvider%20%3C-%20appFacilityList%20%3C-NaNacilityController 
minErr/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:68:12 
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4397:19
```

**Facility Controller**

```
app.controller('facilityController', 
    ['$scope','$rootScope','$location','$filter', 'facilityService', 'appFacilityList','facilityDTO',
    function ($scope,$rootScope,$location,$filter, facilityService,appFacilityList,facilityDTO) {

    }
);
```

**app.js**

```
.state('facility.newFacility', {
    url: '/newFacility',
    views: {
        header: {
            templateUrl: "/views/common/layout/navbar.html"
        },
        facilityHome: {
            templateUrl: '/views/facility/newFacility.html',
            controller: 'facilityController',
            resolve: {
                facilityDTO  : function() {
                    return null;
                },
                appFacilityList  : function( ) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        },
        footer: {
            templateUrl: "/views/common/layout/footer.html"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: can you also paste `appFacilityList` code the problem is appFacilityList could not be injected so just check that section

Comment: What happens when you return an empty object `{}` instead of `null` in the resolves?

Comment: @VadiemJanssens :- Same thing happen there as well.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appFacilityListProvider <- appFacilityList <- facilityController

Comment: @Cyril 
appFacilityList inject to the controller and this define as null from app.js  $stateProvider section.

Comment: if I remove the  `<div class="well" ng-controller="facilityController as controller">` from html its work fine.

Comment: Check the order of `<script></script>` tags. They matters.

Comment: thanks @OrkhanAlikhanov. 
But problem still same here.

Comment: could you provide all of these(appFacilityListProvider <- appFacilityList <- facilityController )?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appFacilityListProvider <- appFacilityList <- facilityController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=appFacilityListProvider%20%3C-%20appFacilityList%20%3C-NaNacilityController
minErr/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4397:19 ......
......

Comment: I meant their decleration

Comment: appFacilityList declaration in the **app.js** 

`resolve: {
                                facilityDTO  : function() {
                                    return null;
                                },
                                appFacilityList  : function( ) {
                                    return null;
                                }`

Comment: I think,somewheer you re-writing your module.Please check it

Comment: @R.J
I think too.. when i click twice error mention like this
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
appFacilityListProvider <- appFacilityList <- facilityController <- facilityController`

Comment: since you said that if you remove ng-controller from div it works... then why not try removing ng-controller from div and using `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` in facilityHome view. `controller: 'facilityController',controllerAs: 'ctrl'`

Comment: Thanks @nabin .
Its working..... now im using `controllerAs` instead of the `ng-contoller' 
thanks again

Comment: @Sadun89 , glad it worked. I added it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you said that if you remove ng-controller from div it works... then why not try removing ng-controller from div and using `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` in facilityHome view. `controller: 'facilityController',controllerAs: 'ctrl'`